# Active Op-Amp Calculation

Tags: operational-amplifier

Can someone please help me to dissect this active op-amp circuit? I'm trying to find the output voltage at varying frequencies.

[image: Active Op-Omp]

Comment: Which part of the equations are you having trouble with?

Comment: Well, its been about a year since I've had a circuit class and I don't know how to analyze this type of circuit anymore. Just not sure how to break it down in order find the output voltage at different frequencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace passives with their \$s\$ domain equivalents (impedances in the \$s\$-domain, resistances stay the same, capacitors become \$\dfrac{1}{Cs}\$) and remember the ideal model of the opamp: virtual short-circuit between its inputs (i.e. the voltage at the inverting and that at the non-inverting input are the same) and no current is drawn by any of the inputs.

Then you should be able to write the output voltage (in the \$s\$-domain) as a product of the input voltage with a function \$H(s)\$ (this is the transfer function of the circuit) using standard circuit techniques used also for DC (Kirchhoff's laws, generalized Ohm's law, etc.).

\$ V_o = H(s) \cdot V_s \qquad \Leftrightarrow \qquad H(s) = \dfrac{V_o}{V_s} \$

After you have determined \$H(s)\$ just substitute \$s\$ with \$j 2 \pi f\$ (or \$j\omega\$) and compute the modulus of the resulting function: \$|H(j 2 \pi f)|\$. This is the amplitude response of the circuit, i.e. it gives the gain of the circuit as the frequency varies.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. Got me started off in the right direction. One other thing though, how to account for the feedback capacitor when solving the impedance?

Answer (score 1):

That is a Sallen-Key low pass filter. You can start on Wikipedia, or Google for on-line calculators.

Comment: How do you figure it's not unity gain?